# How can Remove "Dot" from Button Of roku by XML or Bright Script

Tags: xml, frontend, roku, brightscript

I have tried all the possible way but could not find the way to resolve.Please help

Comment: Please write the question properly with as much details as possible, so that someone can understand and help.

Answer (score 2):

Just set following button properties:

```
iconUri = ""
focusedIconUri = ""
```

And you will be fine...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. If you want to create a button with your design, you need to make your custom button component which should be extended from the group component. Also if you want to add a custom button background image, you should add a poster to the button and make a poster image be 9-patch image. So it could be extendable.

Comment: He asked to remove the dot, not create a custom button, which is achievable (dot removal)